Kotlin testing lateinit local variable for initialization
I have some code where I'm collecting a value from a flow and want to use it to initialize a lateinit variable. I prefer this approach to using a nullable for this case. But although I'm following the instructions here, I am getting an unresolved reference error. Here's some sample code, where the error is on this::arriving in the conditional test.  I suspect the issue is that arriving is a local variable rather than a class property, but isn't this is supposed to work for local variables as well? What's the right way to reference it?
    fun getFavoriteDetail(favorite: Favorite): FavoriteDetails {
        lateinit var arriving: Airport
        viewModelScope.launch {
            flightSearchRepository.getAirportByIata(favorite.destinationCode).collect { airport ->
                arriving = airport[0] // Should be only one
            }
        }
        if (this::arriving.isInitialized) {
            // Do something useful
        }

For now, I can just use a nullable, but I'd appreciate any insight into how to make this work with lateinit isInitialized.

isInitialized is not available for local properties.. I assume getAirportByIata is asynchronous since you are launching a coroutine. In that case, why would this::arriving.isInitialized ever be true? The coroutine would not have completed when that if is executed.

@Sweeper that's true (depending on the amount of intervening code before the test, which in this case is minimized for the example), but my question was really just about isInitialized. I think your answer is correct and I'll be happy to accept it as such if you post it.

From the documentation here,

To check whether a lateinit var has already been initialized, use
.isInitialized on the reference to that property [...]
This check is only available for properties that are lexically
accessible when declared in the same type, in one of the outer types,
or at top level in the same file.

This means that this is not supported for local properties declared in a function. isInitialized is only available for properties that are declared in a type or at the top level.

For the broader question I was experimenting with solving with that broken code example provided, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78955260/creating-composite-data-class-from-multiple-room-sql-queries-or-one-complex-one

Just a minor terminology nit. Since I am still learning Kotlin I want to get this right: I believe that 'properties' belong to a class, and that local function variables are not considered properties. Is that not correct?

@BobDoolittle the language specification calls then “local properties”, but I’ve seen people calling them different things like “local variables” and many others.
